# Can I own a German car, when residing in the Netherlands while being from Poland

Tags: driving, eu, netherlands

I have a Polish and American passport, but I have never lived in either of those countries, I have instead lived in 6 Asian countries and now the Netherlands. So I am an EU citizen but… I have hardly any connection to Poland, technically my home country? Lets move onto my question, which is actually kind of two fold. Firstly, could I buy a car in Poland, pay Polish insurance, and Polish road tax while living in the Netherlands? If so, how long could I do this before having to drive it back now and then. On the other hand, can I do this with a car from any EU country?

Comment: See [Car registration in another EU country - Netherlands](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/registration-abroad//netherlands/index_en.htm) for a general summary of the regulations about bringing a foreign registered car to the Netherlands. Allthough the site assumes you are moving to the Netherlands, the same rules apply generally when importing a car as a resident. Where the car is **primarily** being used is the bases on which it should registered, taxed and insured.

Comment: Questions about long-term residence in another country belong on [expatriates.se]

Answer (score 10):

Means of transportation are excluded from many rules regarding the EU single market and EU countries, including the Netherlands, often impose specific taxes on cars. To prevent circumventing these rules, many countries impose severe restrictions on using cars registered elsewhere than in your country of residence (citizenship is typically irrelevant and non-residents like tourists are fine using their EU-registered car too).

There are exceptions if you just moved or are a student and a bunch of court cases about company cars and the like but in general, as a resident, [you are not allowed to drive a car registered abroad without paying for the Dutch vehicle tax (bpm) and yearly road tax (mrb)](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/zakelijk/auto_en_vervoer/auto_van_de_onderneming/autokosten/auto_met_buitenlands_kenteken), even for a single day. If you need to use a car registered abroad for less than 14 days, you can apply for an exemption online. You get only a single 14-day exemption per year for a given number plate, which tells you how restrictive the rules are (this is intended for cases like returning home with a rental car after an accident abroad).

Because owning and registering a car in the Netherlands is quite expensive, even compared to other EU countries, I know several people who have done what you envision and pulled it off for a period of time but the law forbids it and is actively enforced.

Comment: What if I am a working student in the Netherlands? I am registered at the city hall and have a BSN number.

Comment: @Bob This is becoming a bit more complicated and I have no direct experience with it. My understanding is that you can buy a car in the Netherlands, with a Dutch number plate but be exempted from the bpm (but not the mrb). You need to follow the procedure detailed at https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/themaoverstijgend/programmas_en_formulieren/vrijstelling_van_belasting_voor_een_motorrijtuig_bij_tijdelijk_verblijf_in_nederland

Comment: Importantly, you will need to have an address abroad and to make sure the car's ownership documents mention it, which might be difficult in your case. The notion is that you would take your car with you at the end of your (temporary) stay in the Netherlands. You will also need evidence from your school regarding the length of your studies.

Comment: I also recall special rules about moving with your car as a student but https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/themaoverstijgend/programmas_en_formulieren/vrijstelling_bpm__vrijstelling_bpm_bij_verhuizing suggest these do not apply anymore.

Comment: Yes it will be difficult, as I learned with getting Polish insurance. But I am curious though, which organization would I need to contact to find out, for certain, if I could legally do this? A lawyer? Or the municipality?

Comment: Yes according to those requirements, I wouldn't be eligible due to the car being bought after the move.

Comment: @Bob The RDW or douane are in charge of this, not sure if they answer queries. There are more details on the various procedures here: https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/auto_en_vervoer/belastingen_op_auto_en_motor/bpm/vrijstelling/

Comment: Regarding insurance, many years ago I personally imported a car to the Netherlands on temporary German plates and, IIRC, I could get it insured with a Dutch insurer even for the short period of time between getting it into the country and completing the formalities/getting the Dutch plates.

Comment: I see, so this seems way to complicated for me. Especially given my weird background that further complicates things. So I'll probably go with a dutch car and see how I'll manage with expenses.

Comment: @Bob Remember that scooter and tomos are not allowed on the motorways, motorcycles are allowed there. So if you need the A12, you need either a car or a motorcycle and there are different licenses for that. (Think in the region of €2000 for a driving license for either, and at least some months but up to a year is not unheard of.) 50cc motor cycles (like tomos and scooters) can go on normal roads. Pedelectric bicycles are going to be the norm but they are (usually) rather expensive. A combination of train and bicycle is the Dutch way for longer distances.

Comment: @Bob Just to stress this point: Your "weird background" doesn't matter here at all. Citizenship in general has exactly zero effect on the requirements for car registration or road taxes in the Netherlands. It's just your residency that matters.

Answer (score 7):

> Firstly, could I buy a car in Poland, pay Polish insurance, and Polish road tax while living in the Netherlands?

No. You can buy the car in Poland, but you will need some insurance to drive it to the Nederlands, but you will have to register it again in the Netherlands.

The issue of the insurance may be more tricky, I do know of some people in Spain using a UK insurer but I do not know if it would be applicable to any EU insurer, or if there are just some that offer this service.

And of course, maybe the Polish insurers may object to covering you if you reside at the Netherlands (with presumably more expensive garage shops); check the insurance policy.

> If so, how long could I do this before having to drive it back now and then.

It does not work like "visa runs". The "counter" does not reset just because you move the vehicle out of the Netherlands. It is your status as a resident that matters.

> On the other hand, can I do this with a car from any EU country?

The same rules apply for any EU car.

The EU common markets leaves outside some excise taxes (as it does for tobacco and alcohol duties) that are to be paid to each country. If you become a resident of the Netherlands, you can bring your car but that will be an import; you will have to register the vehicle in the Netherlands and pay whatever taxes the Dutch government decides to apply.

[This pdf](https://download.belastingdienst.nl/belastingdienst/docs/motor-vehicle-foreign-reg-number-mb7001z1fdeng.pdf) explains that you qualify as a Dutch resident if you have lived there for more than 4 months during the last 6 months. At that time you no longer are a visitor and you must register your car.

You can read more here: https://www.rdw.nl/over-rdw/information-in-english/import/apply-for-dutch-vehicle-license-number-for-eu-or-efta-country-vehicle

Comment: Ok, I see, so basically it has nothing to do with the car. Once I am a registered resident for more than 4 months, my car has to be a dutch car (if it's in the Netherlands). Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise everybody (including Dutch people) would be doing it, buying their cars at some tax haven in order to avoid paying Dutch taxes. AFAIK all of the EU countries work like this

Comment: Gotcha, sorry if this question came across as naive. I'm just young and really wish school would have taught me these things.

Comment: Oh and thank you very much. I really appreciate the clarification!

Comment: Car registration is not also a question of country, in Germany you get even in trouble if you don't register the car in the city you most often live (and you need to register there). Insurance costs depend on where you live, what car and other situations. You might be able to have a foreign insurer, but they will certainly ask a premium for it. (And if you chose not to tell them and the registry you might get in trouble at the first ticket or accident)